# Handle unknown number of undefined objects for logging

Tags: c++

Trying to reproduce something that in C# you would do something like this:

```
 string FormatString(params object[] args) {
      return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, args);
 }
```

And in Obj-c it would look like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void logObjects(id firstObject, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstObject);
    id obj;
    for (obj = firstObject; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(args, id))
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    va_end(args);
}

logObjects(@"foo", [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], @"bar", nil);
```

I'm familiar with variable parameter length but not too sure how to store the args and then send them to std::cout. Is this even possible?

Notice! I want to send any kind of object which can handle the << operator. Just look at this function as a substitute for:

```
std::cout << "test" << someObject << int << someOtherObject;
```

I am using boost and would like to keep it platform independent. This function will be part of a logging class in a shared lib.

Comment: Can you use C++11, or are you limited to C++03?

Comment: everything that works on the major os aka nothing ms spec

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: at the moment i think im using msvc2010 but this has to run with gcc on osx aswell. so I only use native c++ and qt

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in C# too because the format string is missing anyway concept is clear. In C you can do something like this (as seen in [dbgprint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you have variadic macro feature)

```
#define printfex(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

If you're so lucky to use [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) you can write this prototype:

```
template<class... T>
void printfex(const std::string& format, T... args);
```

Comment: Note that the `__VA_ARGS__` approach can only work with primitive types, which makes it nearly pointless.

Comment: I agree but in **C** is better than nothing. In C++ he can mimic Object.ToString() from .NET Framework if he needs something more (it's even more flexible) or to use stdarg.h with cout.

Comment: I didn't mean that as a criticism to your answer, I only thought it warranted a mention. :-]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use run-time variadic parameters in C++- that's a basic fact. You must use the same technique that the C++ streams do - operator overloading. Fortunately, C++ already contains such functionality.

```
void f(const std::stringstream& str) {
    std::cout << str;
}
int main() {
    int i = 5;
    f(std::stringstream() << "i is equal to " << 5);
}
```

Comment: how would this fit in to my function? could I have a var nr of stringstreams?

Comment: but thank you for stating the facts. it felt impossible when I started thinking about it, had no idea how to actually implement it. now i know it's c++, not me :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I don't know very much about C#. Do you want to send a list of parameters to `std::cout`? That's not complicated:

```
void formatString (const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    for (int i=0; i<args.size (); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << args[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And you can store the elements in the following way:

```
std::vector test (2);
test[0] = "one";
test[1] = "two";
formatString (test);
```

**UPDATE**

Copy & Paste this into a .cpp file and compile it. 
You have to implement the `IPrintable` interface for every class you want to log. Maybe is not the most efficient solution but it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class IPrintable
{
public:
    virtual ~IPrintable () { }

    virtual std::string toString () const = 0;
};

class ClassA : public IPrintable
{
public:
    std::string toString () const
    {
        std::string s = "Class A to string";
        return s;
    }
};

class ClassB : public IPrintable
{
public:
    std::string toString () const
    {
        std::string s = "Class B to string";
        return s;
    }
};

void print (const std::vector<IPrintable*> args)
{
    for (int i=0; i<args.size (); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << args[i]->toString () << std::endl;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ClassA a;
    ClassB b;

    std::vector<IPrintable*> v (2);
    v[0] = &a;
    v[1] = &b;

    print (v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to do it with ANY datatype, not just strings.  In C# all objects derive from Object, and implement (among other things) a .ToString method.

Comment: yeah, just any object that has a the <<operator

Comment: Then you have to overload the << operator for every type you can to log: `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& operator, const SomeType& someObject);` And you also will need a base class in order to store different types in the same container

Comment: that's not really possible. what if I want to send in ints, doubles and some other random types which all have the << operator overloaded. i cannot "rederive" them...

Comment: Well...looking at your last comment, you could try to create wrappers for primitive types: `Interger` for `int`, `Double` for `double`, etc.

Comment: I would rather create separate print functions for the different types than do that since it wouldn't be possible to have such a demanding function in a shared library